# text inside the block displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks - block1, block2, block3..block1 & 2 are left floated

http://jsfiddle.net/MTSg4/1/

The text inside block3 needs to be displayed inside the block but for some reason its displaying outside.

css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
#block1{
    height:10%;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;

}

#block2{
    height:90%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
}

#block3{
    height:90%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;

}
```

html

```
<div id="block1">
    Block 1
</div>
<div id="block2">
    Block 2
</div>

<div id="block3">
    Block 3
</div>
```

Comment: Looks what I'd expect to happen. The content for block3 can't appear above where it is unless you start playing with the position of the block. Plus, you changed the height of that div to 90%. Leave it as auto and you'll see it's encompassed in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats in blocks 1 and 2.  Try this for block3:

```
#block3{
    height:90%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of floats is the problem. You see, block 2 is just a trial and error. It does not float left. Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ncqrL/).

```
#block2{
    height:90%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
    float:right;
}

#block3{
    height:90%;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
    float: left;    
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
      #block1 {
      height: 10%; 
      width: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: red;
      display: block;
      float: left;
     }

      #block2 {
      height: 90%; 
      width: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: green;
      display: block;
      float: left;
     }

      #block3 {
      height: 90%; 
      width: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: yellow;
      display: block;
      clear: both;
     }
```

Comment: How is this answer different from sma's who posted it seven minutes before you?

Comment: i didn't see that i saw after i posted

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink the HTML to achieve this.

Perhaps a better solution is to split this into two columns, with block 1 and 2 in the first column, and block 3 in the second?

**HTML**

```
<div id="col1">
  <div id="block1">
      Block 1
  </div>
  <div id="block2">
      Block 2
  </div>
</div>

<div id="col2">
  <div id="block3">
      Block 3
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#col1, #col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

#block1{
  height:10%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:red; 
}

#block2{
  height:90%;
  background-color:green;
}

#block3{
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/ncqrL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
 html, body{
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    #block1{
        height:10%;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        background-color:red;

    }

    #block2{
        height:90%;
        width:50%;
        background-color:green;
        float:right;
    }

    #block3{
        height:90%;
        width:50%;
        background-color:yellow;
        float: left;

    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
        content: ' ';
        *zoom: 1;
    }
    }
```

in your HTML:

```
<div id="block1">
    Block 1
</div>
<div id="block2">
    Block 2
</div>
<div id="block3">
    Block 3
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

This happens because the "block3" is floating around and not in a position while the other boxes are being called in left (including the box2 [It should be float: right]).
I've fixed and and added a debug class (clear).

Jsfiddle: [Demostration](http://jsfiddle.net/MTSg4/4/)
Hope it helps!